# Replace and modify String using regex in java

Tags: java, html

I have a part of HTML from a website in the below String format:

srcset="                    /tesla_theme/assets/img/homepage/mobile/homepage-models--touch@200w.jpg?20170808 200w,                    /tesla_theme/assets/img/homepage/mobile/homepage-models--touch@338w.jpg?20170808 338w,                    /tesla_theme/assets/img/homepage/mobile/homepage-models--touch@445w.jpg?20170808 445w,                    tesla_theme/assets/img/homepage/mobile/homepage-models--touch@542w.jpg?20170808 542w,                    /tesla_theme/assets/img/homepage/mobile/homepage-models--touch@750w.jpg?20170808 750w"

I want to add http://tesla.com in front of all the urls in the srcset element like http://tesla_theme/assets/img/homepage/mobile/homepage-models--touch@750w.jpg?20170808 750w

I believe this could be done using regex, but I am not sure.

How do I do this using Java if I have multiple srcset elements in a html string variable, and I want to replace all of the srcset url.'s and add the server url in front?

Note: The /tesla_theme will not be consistent, so I cannot use replaceAll, instead, i will have to use regex.

Comment: You have a complete html in string format in java? or just the srcset? you can try this  srcset = srcset.replaceAll("/tesla_theme", "http://tesla.com/tesla_theme");

Comment: I have a complete html in string format. And Also its not specific to just tesla.com, but any also keeping in mind that it could be for other Urls too.

Comment: Do you mean relative URL to http appended URL?

Comment: Correct. It is not just specific to tesla. I have a tool which gets html from a url provided. So in this html it gets, if there is a srcset element, I want the links inside the srcset appended with the host url in front.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use String Class replace method as below, It will replace all "/_tesla" in the given String. No special regex required unless you have a kind of pattern instead of "/tesla"

```
String srcset=" /tesla_theme/assets/img/homepage/mobile/homepage-models--touch@200w.jpg?20170808 200w, /tesla_theme/assets/img/homepage/mobile/homepage-models--touch@338w.jpg?20170808 338w, /tesla_theme/assets/img/homepage/mobile/homepage-models--touch@445w.jpg?20170808 445w, tesla_theme/assets/img/homepage/mobile/homepage-models--touch@542w.jpg?20170808 542w, /tesla_theme/assets/img/homepage/mobile/homepage-models--touch@750w.jpg?20170808 750w";

String requiredSrcSet = srcset.replace("/tesla_", "http://tesla_");
```

Comment: There is a pattern. It won't be tesla all the time. So since it will not be consistent, I will need to use regex